# How secure is an Azure database within Microsoft?

Tags: security, azure-sql-database

I am considering moving most of my Databases to Azure SQL server Database, but I am concerned that Microsoft will be able to snoop and look at the data inside the database, which is absolutely not acceptable.

- Can Microsoft see any data in an Azure AQL DB?
- What is the extent of Microsoft ability to influence a database in Azure?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to be secure, is to control your data. If someone else is running it on its own infrastructure, they are able to read, change or use them. Period. 
For example: if your database is confidential one, you should not use someone else infrastructure.
Saying that ( which is completely obvious), you may assume, that as long as you not breaking the law, and USA is not in political conflict with your country, Microsoft is not interested in peeking at your data, **exactly as any other company**

So if you have something to hide, use your own server. If you have nothing special ( and putting it on the web is in compliance with local law) go on.

Answer (score 1):

*<sub>[Community wiki answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki):</sub>*

Unless you actually give someone an account to your system, Microsoft cannot read your data.

They can see the configuration of items but security is one of their strong points.

See [Compliance for Microsoft cloud services](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/trustcenter/compliance/default.aspx) for all the various compliances they will help your organization with (HIPAA, PCI, etc.).

See also [Responding to government and law enforcement requests to access customer data](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/trustcenter/privacy/govt-requests-for-data) in the Microsoft Trust Center.

> We do not provide any government with our encryption keys or the ability to break our encryption.

Comment: Not sure this true. Maybe they say they won't but, they could if they wanted to. Unless the data is encrypted.  But then the encryption script is probably owned by MS, and they probably share it with governments if they ask.